# Delete all lines from middle of a line matching a string until the second string match is found

Tags: text-processing, sed, awk

I am trying to remove the error messages printed into my file.
I have this:

```
 addr:1122c:1234:
 addr:11230:5678:
 addr:11223:01Error:abcdef(x, y) = z, value = a
Error:hijklm(v, q) = w, value = b
Error:nopqrst(x, y) = z, value = d
Error:uvwxyz(l, m) = z, value = e
Error:1234(u, t) = z, value = f
Error:567(r, s) = z, value = g
err_total = 9846, err_sub = 0, err_mask = 239
1 Duration: xyz, abc
0 Duration: pqr, def
23:
 addr:11238:4567:
 addr:1123c:8901:
```

I need to remove all the error messages upto the next addr appears. 
Required output is:

```
 addr:1122c:1234:
 addr:11230:5678:
 addr:11223:0123:
 addr:11238:4567:
 addr:1123c:8901:
```

I have tried:

```
sed -i "/\bError\b/d" file_name
```

But this removes the lines starting from Error and did not remove the line where Error string started from the middle.

I am new to regular expressions, an explaination would be really helpful.

Edit:
I am using `sed -i '/Error/,/addr/d' filename` 
but this removes the whole line and does not give what I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`sed` is not really good in Multiline Matching.
You can trick it to do what you want, but then imo `perl` is easier to handle.

Try this:

```
perl -pe 'BEGIN{undef $/;}; s/Error.*?(^[0-9]* Duration: [^\n]*\n)+//smg;'
```

Explanation:

- `BEGIN { do_something; }`: Do something once at the beginning
- `undef $/`: Ignore line endings
- `s///` Substitute
- `Error.*` Match any string beginning with "Error".
- `?` Make the previous match ungreedy, for that it stops at the following match or in this case matching group...
- `()+` Make a matching group, that needs to be matched at least once (`+`).
- `^[0-9]* Duration: [^\n]*\n`: Match the whole line with Duration including.

([via](https://serverfault.com/a/272036))

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works like a charm for the example i gave. However, I had a different example I was working on. I have updated the question, can u please take a look and suggest changes?

Comment: Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

Rather than deleting the "`Error:`" lines, why not extract just the lines you want with:

```
grep -E '^ addr:' file_name | sed -e 's/Error:.*//'
```

Comment: I have other lines in the file that does not begin with 'addr' but are needed. Hence I asked for way to remove the unwanted lines.

Comment: I refuse to track a problem that's revealed a tiny bit at a time. You keep changing requirements, and that's unacceptable.

Comment: Sorry for the miscommunication, my intention was just to remove the unwanted lines and I guess I dint convey it in the best way. Nevertheless, thank you for your answer, upvoted.

Answer (score 1):

This will generate the output you have been looking for:

```
$ cat file_name | grep -v \
    -e '^Error:' \
    -e '^err_total' \
    -e '^.*[0-9] Duration:' | \
    sed ':a;$!N;s/Error:.*\n\(.*[0-9]\):/\1:/;ta;P;D'
```

Frist remove all the `Error`, `err_total`, and `12345 Duration:` stuff. Then search for the `Error: ...` interrupting your output, remove the newline(`\n`), search for the next occurence of a number (`.*[0-9]:`) an append it to the current line.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, works like a charm for the example i gave. However, I had a different example I was working on. I have updated the question, can u please take a look and suggest changes?